# Chromium graphics messed up after installing ATI fglrx drivers

Tags: ati, chromium, fglrx

I have been troubleshooting display problems - my computer was using default Ubuntu drivers and I finally managed to get the proprietary fglrx-update to work instead. Finally the display seems to use hardware acceleration. This speeds up the dash considerably.

Now after a few minutes of use, I notice that my Chromium title bar and/or tab bar and/or bookmarks bar get thoroughly messed up when I add another tab. Sometimes just the bookmarks bar (or even just parts of it!), sometimes the tabs, sometimes everything - see this example:

Top: typical error.
Bottom: what it normally looks like.

[image: messed up]

I can "fix" it by mousing over the area or by switching to another app and back. This hasn't *ever* happened before so it's a fair guess that the `fglrx-update` drivers are to blame.
--> How can I fix this?